# “Synchronize” does not show the difference between local files and the TFS head in Eclipse/TFS – is it a bug?

Tags: eclipse, tfs

Somehow, I found that my “Check In Pending Changes” were not propagated into the TFS head. At the same time “Synchronize” showed the complete correspondence between my local files and TFS.

So, nothing in Eclipse TFS showed the difference between local files and the repository.  Only “Detect Local Changes” showed the difference.   Why this happens for the files already checked in into the repository?  Is it a bug?

Comment: Sounds like not.  If "detect local changes" is finding files, it sounds like changes aren't getting pended in the first place.  Are you using a server or local workspace?

Comment: Sorry, did not understand what you mean by "Are you using a server or local workspace?"  The repository is on the server and I am working locally with my workspace